# TYPO3 Extbase query with CONCAT

Tags: mysql, typo3, extbase

Is it possible to use CONCAT in an extbase query like this one?

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query
  ->matching(
    $query->logicalOr(
      $query->like('street', '%' . $search . '%'),
      $query->like('street_number', '%' . $search . '%'),
    )
  )
  ->execute();
```

Now, I'ld like to also query for CONCAT(street, ' ', street_number).

The resulting SQL query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE street LIKE '%abc%' OR street_number LIKE '%abc%' OR CONCAT(street, ' ', street_number) LIKE '%abc%';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Doctrine DBAL you can use `getConcatExpression` from `DatabasePlatform` of your current `Connection` to the table:

```
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
$queryBuilder = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('myTable');
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Connection $connection */
$connection = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable('myTable');
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select('*')
    ->from('myTable')
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->like(
                'street',
                $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%abc%', \PDO::PARAM_STR)
            ),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->like(
                'street_number',
                $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%abc%', \PDO::PARAM_STR)
            ),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->comparison(
                $connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getConcatExpression('street, \' \', street_number'),
                'LIKE',
                $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%abc%', \PDO::PARAM_STR)
            )
        )
    )
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not work in `update` queries. The value there is always quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You may use statement() for this kind of query if you are using TYPO3 below version 8 LTS.

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query
  ->statement('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE street LIKE "%abc%" OR street_number LIKE "%abc%" OR CONCAT(street, " ", street_number) LIKE "%abc%"')
  )
  ->execute();
```

In TYPO3 8 LTS the new Doctrine DBAL should have functions for this, too. But I don't have a snippet next to my hand right now.

Comment: I hoped there is a better solution than using function "statement". If I find an example for Doctrine DBAL, I will post it here.